# How is this code adding a number to a datetime without using DATEADD?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the following SQL statement there's some T-SQL that adds a number to a `datetime` and to a `date`:

```
declare @t table(UserID int, StartDate datetime, EndDate date)
insert @t select 1, '20110101', '20110102' 

-- Adding int to a datetime works
select t.StartDate + 2 as NewStartDate

-- Adding int to a date errors
select t.EndDate + 2 as NewEndDate
```

I would expect both of the above select statements to fail because neither are using the `DATEADD` method, but to my surprise adding an `int` to a `datetime` without using `DATEADD` works. Why is that?

Comment: Are you sure your column is `DateTime` datatype not `Date`? BTW, there is no _fields_ those are _columns_.

Comment: @Sami I've reworded the question now to hopefully bring it back on topic, let me know if it needs further amendment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a number to a `datetime`.  It is interpreted as a number of days.

Perhaps surprisingly, SQL Server does not support adding an integer to `date`.

So, this works:

```
select getdate() + 1
```

But this generates an error:

```
select cast(getdate() as date) + 1
```

This is sort of explained in the documentation for [+ (operator)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/add-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> expression
>
> Is any valid expression of any one of the data types in the numeric category except the bit data type. Cannot be used with `date`, `time`, `datetime2`, or `datetimeoffset` data types.

I mean, anyone reading this would immediately notice that `datetime` is in the "numeric" category and missing from the list of types that are not supported.

I should note that this functionality also allows adding two `datetime` values.  This is handy for adding a "time" (cast to `datetime`) to a date (cast to `datetime`).

Comment: Datetime2 fails as well.

Comment: @tomRedox **Column** not _Field_

Comment: @tomRedox People here say that all the time but I find it extremely nitpicky at best.  I wouldn't worry about it.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/65614/97884

Comment: It's not a good thing to do, it's just sloppy coding, anyway. Always use DATEADD because someone may decide to change the datatype and it'd break everything.